# How is shared dll (GAC ) loaded to memory and used in comparison to private dll

Tags: dll, gac

I'd like to point out that I know how to add/remove assembles to/from GAC. What I am asking for is if someone could explain me how does it work from the technical point of view. What's the point in putting dll's there - from the point of view of saving the resources.

Kind Regards
pk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of putting things in the GAC is so that multiple applications (even from different vendors) can access the same assembly.  There is then one location where it can be updated and all applications which can properly access that version can use it.  You also know that all assemblies in the GAC are digitally signed, so you know where the code came from (MS for example).

As far as loading into memory. Each application will have to load it on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538710/why-should-i-not-use-the-gac) gives a good argument for not using the GAC where you can avoid it.

And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134485/best-gac-tutorial-overview) gives a couple of links to GAC demystification articles which may help your decision.