# ClickOnce deployment "System.IO.IOException"

Tags: .net, winforms, clickonce

I'm trying to deploy an application by ClickOnce deployment. Clicking on the setup.exe initiates the installation but suddenly dialog box prompts saying that

```
An Error has occured writing to the hard disk.Check if there is enough available space on the disk.Contact the application vendor!
```

When I click the `Details` button of the dialog box, it shows the inner exception,stacktrace,...
and here is the useful part of the exception message:

```
System.IO.IOException
        - The file 'E:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\Deployment\JO85B12B.BBL\N1TJQM37.HZ5\Microsoft.ExceptionMessageBox.dll' already exists.
        - Source: mscorlib
```

It also worth saying that, this is the package for a project called Project A, referencing a second project, say Project B which needed to be included in the ClickOnce package, so I have mark it as `Include`  in the Project A properties. And `Microsoft.ExceptionMessageBox.dll` which's been mentioned in exception is used in both projects, so I've marked that as include in both places (although on my machine `Microsoft.ExceptionMessageBox.dll` is in the `GAC` (as a part of SQL Server), it is not available on client's PC, so that's why I have included that on the package as well)

Comment: What exactly are you using? .NET V.xx? Visual Basic, C++, it would be helpful to include this kind of information.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm using C#.Net 3.5

Comment: That full HDD error is a red herring. See here - another person reported the exact same problem you have here: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/clickonce-deployment-problem-t2334722.html - Use this SO thread to get you out of trouble: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099962/deploy-my-dlls-to-gac-for-use-with-clickonce-app

Answer (score 3):

I had a dll that was giving me this problem.  I went to the project's properties >> Publish Tab >> Click the Application Files button >>

- Set the "Publish Status" to "Include" for the File in question.
- Create a new "Download Group" for the assembly that's giving you problems and select it (I don't know why this worked).
- Publish.